# Opencart 1.4.9.4 redirects on Lighttpd 1.4.19-5+lenny2

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, lighttpd, opencart, lighty

Recently I've been looking into Opencart as a solution for simple E-commerce websites. I like it a lot, but I can't seem to get the redirection right.

I am using lighttpd as a web server, and I've noticed that Opencart offers Apache .htaccess configuration for SEO URL's, but no luck for lighttpd.

Opencart uses URLs that are formed like this:

- Login Page: `http://[domain]/index.php?route=account/login`
- Product Page: `http://[domain]/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=51`

Ideally, I would like to have something like this:

- Login Page: `http://[domain]/index.php/account/login`
- Product Page: `http://[domain]/index.php/product/51/[product-name]`

Of course, any pointers in the right direction are highly appreciated. Even a short explanation of where to find the right way to handle rewrites in Lighty would be helpful!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people have had issues with 1 4 19-5lenny and earlier apparently. If you want to rewrite urls the way you have above, you will need to parse them yourself using your own custom hook (see the preAction in the index.php for handling them by default). Note that you will also need to manually edit urls like the account one since they aren't even sent through the url rewriter before being output